# Can Push to Heroku But Can't Run Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rake, dbmigrate

I can push a Rails app to Heroku with ...

    `git push heroku`

but when I try to migrate with ...

    `heroku run rake db:migrate`

I get ...

`Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... failed
     !    You do not have access to the app my-app-name-1234.`

Edit: my .git/config contains ...

    `[remote "heroku"]
            url = git@heroku.com:young-mist-1198.git
            fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*`

Any ideas? Things look reasonable on the Heroku side and it seems like if my ssh key were bad, it wouldn't even let me push.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I figured it out and in case it helps someone else ...
`heroku auth:login`

somehow I was not authorized and just needed to re-login.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
heroku run bash --app appname
heroku run rake db:migrate
```